# how to deploy .net core web api to linux machine

Tags: .net, linux, docker, asp.net-core, .net-core

I created a web api application using .net core, and I want to deploy to linux using docker. How to do it ?

I add this (--server.urls) inside project.json in "commands" section,
so it becomes like this :

```
"commands": {
    "web": "Microsoft.AspNet.Server.Kestrel --server.urls http://0.0.0.0:5000",
  },
```

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM microsoft/aspnet:1.0.0-rc1-update1-coreclr

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dnu", "restore"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["dnx", "-p", "project.json", "web"]
```

I can successfully created a docker image, using this command
docker build -t myapp .

but when i run the docker

docker run -d -t -p 80:5000 myapp, it threw an error

```
"Error response from daemon: driver failed programming external connectivity on endpoint kickass_hopper (16d5675978b188131670f391614f7f89b6ec977ae88924ae422a9a9c18768f22): iptables failed: iptables --wait -t nat -A DOCKER -p tcp -d 0/0 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 172.17.0.2:5000 ! -i docker0: iptables: No chain/target/match by that name.
 (exit status 1)."
```

Anybody know what happen ?

Comment: This discussion may be useful for you: [No DOCKER chain in iptables](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/1871)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you have got the configuration correct, although I'd compile the dot net core application first before creating a docker image, simply because dnu restore can be temperamental.

Here's a blog I wrote based upon creating a Docker container with Dot Net Core API, which may help (although it based upon RC2):

http://fuzzyduckdev.blogspot.com/2016/07/aspnet-core-apis-with-docker.html